# Using the OVER window function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How would I get the total count of a limited result with SQLAlchemy. I am currently using Postgres so I know I can use windowed functions. I basically want to know how I would write the following in SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT foo
  ,count(*) OVER() AS full_count
FROM   bar
ORDER  BY <some col>
LIMIT  <pagesize>
OFFSET <offset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
select(
    [
        bar.c.foo,
        func.count().over().label('full_count'),
    ],
    ...
)
```

Ticket where this was introduced: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/1844#comment:9

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I would also add that the following imports were needed: `from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select` and `from sqlalchemy import func`.