# Python SQLAlchemy Query using labeled OVER clause with ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This other question says how to use the OVER clause on sqlalchemy:

[Using the OVER window function in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598610/using-the-over-window-function-in-sqlalchemy)

But how to do that using ORM?  I have something like:

```
q = self.session.query(self.entity, func.count().over().label('count_over'))
```

This fails when I call `q.all()` with the following message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
Ambiguous column name 'count(*) OVER ()' in result set! try 'use_labels' option on select statement
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

You have the [`over`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) syntax almost correct, it should be something like this:

```
import sqlalchemy
q = self.session.query(
    self.entity,
    sqlalchemy.over(func.count()).label('count_over'),
)
```

Example from the docs:

```
from sqlalchemy import over
over(func.row_number(), order_by='x')
```

Answer (score 3):

SQLAlchemy Query object has `with_entities` method that can be used to customize the list of columns the query returns:

```
Model.query.with_entities(Model.foo, func.count().over().label('count_over'))
```

Resulting in following SQL:

```
SELECT models.foo AS models_foo, count(*) OVER () AS count_over FROM models
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the functions right. They way to use them to produce the desired result would be as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
q = self.session.query(self.entity, func.count(self.entity).over().label('count_over'))
```

This will produce a `COUNT(*)` statement since no `Entity.field` was specified. I use the following format:

```
from myschema import MyEntity
from sqlalchemy import func
q = self.session.query(MyEntity, func.count(MyEntity.id).over().label('count'))
```

That is if there is an id field, of course. But you get the mechanics :-)