# Python SQLAlchemy raw query count + results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following query and I need to add it the `func.count().over().label('full_count')` like described by sayap in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600064/7123717), but i absolutely don't know how :(.

Here is my query :

```py
paginated_sql_query = "SELECT *, count(*) OVER() AS full_count FROM sim_cards " + sql_query

if per_page > 0:
   paginated_sql_query = paginated_sql_query + " LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset"
   parameters["limit"] = per_page
   parameters["offset"] = (page - 1) * per_page

result_rows = session.execute(
   select(SimCards)
   .from_statement(text(paginated_sql_query)), parameters)
   .scalars()
```

I tried to pass an array on the select like that but without result :( :

```py
result_rows = session.execute(
   select( [SimCards, func.count().over().label('full_count')] )
   .from_statement(text(paginated_sql_query)), parameters )
   .scalars()
```

My need is to have the total count in only one query with my paginated results and to know how to exploit it after.

Comment: dont paginate if you want the entire count. Also what is the error/wrong output you are getting ?

Comment: @leoOrion it seems that the count is the total one, not only the paginated one.
My error is this is one : 

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: Could not locate column in row for column 'count(*) OVER ()'

Comment: is there a clumn called `full_count` in the view being selected ?

Comment: When you say "the view" you mean SimCards in my case ? If yes, the answer is no because SimCards is SQLAlchemy Model and the full_count is a dynamic information created with the query

Comment: I mean in the columns that will appear after selection is done. It would help if you post the query.

Comment: @leoOrion i added the SELECT part of the query in my post. The "sql_query" param is a concat of different joins etc. I didn't write the code, i think it would be better to rewrite it but i don't have the time for.